# signalR not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: signalr

I'm getting the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8099//negotiate?_=1348566460118. Origin http://localhost:49848 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

If I run the below code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var con = $.connection("http://127.0.0.1:8099/");
        $.connection.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8099/signalr";

        con.start({ transport: 'auto', xdomain: true }, function () {
           console.log('connection started!');
       });




    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with the code:

1) You're missing a script reference to /signalr/hubs.

In your case it must come from the self-hosted server. So you need to add:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8099/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

2) Your con variable is not pointing to the correct object.

Instead of

```
var con = $.connection("http://127.0.0.1:8099/");
```

it should be

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

var con = $.connection.hub;
con.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8099/signalr";

con.start(function() {
    console.log('connection started!');
});
```